# JWT Invalidate Token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

1. I am using express js with mongodb
2. Using jsonwebtoken for authentication
3. after successful login i put a token in cookies
4. For incoming requested data i check the token in cookies. if token is valid i
   re-generate token and puts new token in cookies and response
   requested data (just like refreshing token for each request).

Till now everything working fine and no use of db

I want to invalidate old token without db, but seems that it is impossible So doing thing as mentioned below.

1. For successful login i set the cookies with jwt token. Also store
   that token in an array and user's info document in db too.
2. For each request for data i validate the token and check the token
   present in array matching or not, if match i delete that token from
   array generate new token put new token in array and user's info
   document in db, again set new token in cookies and response data.

Above step also working fine and i am able to invalidate old token

But what if server down?? If server down all token for each users lost and all are forcefully logout

For preventing that issue i check the token in user's info document in db if token for matching token

By doing this step, no need to go in db and check for valid token or not. Db lookup only when token not present in array.

**My question is for security and speed performance**

Question is this implementation good? Is speed performance will be good as users increase and so many token in array for each user. Means need looping all token for matching a token in array.

Sorry for bad english

Comment: It seems you are shoehorning a stateless authentication method into a stateful process. Why do you even use JWT for that in the first place?